# Can you use Microsoft Graph API in JavaScript to get list items?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm using the samples for the MSAL and converting them to use MS Graph to read SharePoint but when it comes to reading list items it seems I am getting permissions issues.

To make sure I have my syntax correct, I use the Graph Explorer with my AD account and I am able to read list items and confirm the URI is correct. I am also able to read and get an array of lists. But as soon as I try to get the list items for a list nothing is returned.

The base code is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa

Here's the code I converted from the sample. If you update the variables and register in Azure you should be able to run against your SPO site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quickstart for MSAL JS</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.0/js/msal.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to MSAL.js Quickstart</h2><br />
    <h4 id="WelcomeMessage"></h4>
    <button id="SignIn" onclick="signIn()">Sign In</button><br /><br />
    <button id="btnAllLists" onclick="GetWithEndPoint()">Get All Lists</button><br /><br />
    <button id="btnListItems" onclick="GetWithEndPoint()">Get List Items</button><br /><br />
    <button id="btnListItemsAllFields" onclick="GetWithEndPoint()">Get List Items All Fields</button><br /><br />
    <pre id="json"></pre>
    <script>
        var config = {
            portalname: "yourportalname",
            sitename: "yoursitename",
            listid: "guidofalist"
        }
        var msalConfig = {
            auth: {
                clientId: "azureclientguid",
                authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourportal.onmicrosoft.com"
            },
            cache: {
                cacheLocation: "localStorage",
                storeAuthStateInCookie: true
            }
        };
        var graphConfig = {
            graphMeEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
            spShowAllListsEp: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/" + config.portalname + ".sharepoint.com:/sites/" + config.sitename + ":/lists",
            spShowListItemsEp: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/" + config.portalname + ".sharepoint.com:/sites/" + config.sitename + ":/lists/" + config.listid + "/items",
            spShowListItemsAllFieldsEp: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/" + config.portalname + ".sharepoint.com:/sites/" + config.sitename + ":/lists/" + config.listid + "/items?expand=fields",
        };
        // this can be used for login or token request, however in more complex situations this can have diverging options
        var requestObj = {
            scopes: ["user.read"]
        };
        var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

        // Register Callbacks for redirect flow
        myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);

        function callMSGraph(theUrl, accessToken, callback) {
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                    callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
            xmlHttp.send();
        }

        function signIn() {
            myMSALObj.loginPopup(requestObj).then(function (loginResponse) {
                //Login Success
                showWelcomeMessage();
                acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }

        function acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph() {
            //Always start with acquireTokenSilent to obtain a token in the signed in user from cache
            myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {
                callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint, tokenResponse.accessToken, graphAPICallback);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                // Upon acquireTokenSilent failure (due to consent or interaction or login required ONLY)
                // Call acquireTokenPopup(popup window)
                if (requiresInteraction(error.errorCode)) {
                    myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {
                        callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint, tokenResponse.accessToken, graphAPICallback);
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        function graphAPICallback(data) {
            document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        }

        function showWelcomeMessage() {
            var divWelcome = document.getElementById('WelcomeMessage');
            divWelcome.innerHTML = 'Welcome ' + myMSALObj.getAccount().userName + "to Microsoft Graph API";
            var loginbutton = document.getElementById('SignIn');
            loginbutton.innerHTML = 'Sign Out';
            loginbutton.setAttribute('onclick', 'signOut();');
            var btn1 = document.getElementById('btnAllLists');
            btn1.setAttribute('onclick', "GetWithEndPoint('" + graphConfig.spShowAllListsEp + "');");
            var btn2 = document.getElementById('btnListItems');
            btn2.setAttribute('onclick', "GetWithEndPoint('" + graphConfig.spShowListItemsEp + "');");
            var btn3 = document.getElementById('btnListItemsAllFields');
            btn3.setAttribute('onclick', "GetWithEndPoint('" + graphConfig.spShowListItemsAllFieldsEp + "');");
        }

        //This function can be removed if you do not need to support IE
        function acquireTokenRedirectAndCallMSGraph() {
            //Always start with acquireTokenSilent to obtain a token in the signed in user from cache
            myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {
                callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphMeEndpoint, tokenResponse.accessToken, graphAPICallback);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                // Upon acquireTokenSilent failure (due to consent or interaction or login required ONLY)
                // Call acquireTokenRedirect
                if (requiresInteraction(error.errorCode)) {
                    myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect(requestObj);
                }
            });
        }

        function authRedirectCallBack(error, response) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else {
                if (response.tokenType === "access_token") {
                    callMSGraph(graphConfig.graphEndpoint, response.accessToken, graphAPICallback);
                } else {
                    console.log("token type is:" + response.tokenType);
                }
            }
        }

        function requiresInteraction(errorCode) {
            if (!errorCode || !errorCode.length) {
                return false;
            }
            return errorCode === "consent_required" ||
                errorCode === "interaction_required" ||
                errorCode === "login_required";
        }
        function signOut() {
            myMSALObj.logout();
        }

        // Browser check variables
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
        var msie11 = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
        var msedge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
        var isIE = msie > 0 || msie11 > 0;
        var isEdge = msedge > 0;
        //If you support IE, our recommendation is that you sign-in using Redirect APIs
        //If you as a developer are testing using Edge InPrivate mode, please add "isEdge" to the if check
        // can change this to default an experience outside browser use
        var loginType = isIE ? "REDIRECT" : "POPUP";

        if (loginType === 'POPUP') {
            if (myMSALObj.getAccount()) {// avoid duplicate code execution on page load in case of iframe and popup window.
                showWelcomeMessage();
                acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();
            }
        }
        else if (loginType === 'REDIRECT') {
            document.getElementById("SignIn").onclick = function () {
                myMSALObj.loginRedirect(requestObj);
            };
            if (myMSALObj.getAccount() && !myMSALObj.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {// avoid duplicate code execution on page load in case of iframe and popup window.
                showWelcomeMessage();
                acquireTokenRedirectAndCallMSGraph();
            }
        } else {
            console.error('Please set a valid login type');
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        function GetWithEndPoint(endpointString) {
            myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {
                callMSGraph(endpointString, tokenResponse.accessToken, graphAPICallback);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                if (requiresInteraction(error.errorCode)) {
                    myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(requestObj).then(function (tokenResponse) {
                        callMSGraph(endpointString, tokenResponse.accessToken, graphAPICallback);
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Clicking either button that returns list items throws this message which I understand to mean is permissions.

```
    {
      "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.list)('myid')/items",
      "value": []
    }
```

My expectation is that I would get the same results from the Graph Explorer. But this indicates I don't have permission. I've tried a few different lists and the results are always the same. I can get a list of all the lists. But trying to get the items from a list fails.

Can we not use the Graph API with JS to get list items?

Here are the Azure delegated permissions from Azure which I think should be all I need to get list items.
[image: azure site permissions]
[image: azure file permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this indicates I don't have permission

That's right, empty results usually indicates one of the following permissions (delegated permissions in your case) are missing for [`Get Items` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs):

- `Sites.Read.All` - read items in all site collections
- `Sites.ReadWrite.All` - edit or delete items in all site collections

Comment: I am 99% sure I have the read all for sites but I will try to get a screen print to verify. I did not include read/write thinking it wasn't needed. I think I also included read for files thinking the list items were considered as file items but I will get screen prints to verify that as well.

Comment: I've added the screen print of the azure permissions. I even added read/write just to see if that made a difference and still empty array. I also confirm that I do have access by using a browser window.

Comment: @pretzelb, could you confirm the access token `scp` claim contain `Sites.Read.All` scope, it could be validated for example [here](https://jwt.io/)

Comment: Looks like you are on to something. Using the URL you gave me the I see `"scp": "User.Read profile openid email"`. I assume this means that even though I updated the permissions in Azure, I am not getting those back in my token. In the Azure portal, when you update the API permissions you get the message `Permissions have changed. Users and/or admins will have to consent even if they have already done so previously.` but I do NOT get asked for consent on the new permissions. Is there a way to force the check for consent? I'm going to look into that.

Comment: Great job in helping me find this. I knew it had to be something simple I was overlooking. In this case it was the sample code I had started with contained this config `var requestObj = {scopes: ["user.read"]};` which was overriding everything I did in the portal. Really stupid mistake on my part. Once I added `sites.read.all` to that variable it worked. I could have also removed that line I bet. I was going to post a separate reply with the final code but instead I just voted this as the solution. Thanks a bunch.